# rollup.js single import multiple usages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rollupjs

hello rollup experts

i have a single react component and a store that are using the same import

//file: ProfileStore.js

```
import ProfilesActions from './ProfilesActions.js'
....
```

--

//file: Component.js

```
import ProfilesStore from '../flux/ProfilesStore'
....
render: function() {
    ....
    ProfilesActions.doSomething();
    ....
}
```

My output result is very weird :

```
var ProfilesActions$1 = .....//The ProfileActions implementation 

var ProfilesStore = ....
    ProfilesActions$1.doSomething 

var Component = ....
    ProfilesActions.getMoreProfiles();
```

how can i tell rollup.js to use the single instance of `ProfilesActions` without the suffix `$1`

thank you very much

Comment: Do you import `ProfilesActions` from your `Component.js` file? Or are you trying to rely on the fact that it's imported in `ProfileStore.js`?

Comment: You need to import `ProfilesActions` too in your component code. Rollup uses `treeshaking` to import the resources and it (ProfilesActions) will be included only once in build. Give entry point to your main app.js file. I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

i learned that i have to call import on all places that using `ProfilesActions`.

so this means also importing in the `Component.js`

thank to @Clavin and @Akansh Gulati for helping.